# How to use --set to set values with Prometheus chart?

Tags: json, yaml, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

For example, set `alertmanager.ingress.annotations` to add two items, both of these two methods not work:

```
$ helm install stable/prometheus \
  --set alertmanager.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set "alertmanager.ingress.annotations={alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing, alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=dev,Team=test}"

Error: YAML parse error on prometheus/templates/alertmanager-ingress.yaml: error unmarshaling JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field .annotations of type map[string]string
$ helm install stable/prometheus \
  --set alertmanager.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set "alertmanager.ingress.annotations={'alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme': 'internet-facing', 'alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags': 'Environment=dev,Team=test'}"

Error: YAML parse error on prometheus/templates/alertmanager-ingress.yaml: error unmarshaling JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field .annotations of type map[string]string
```

So how to use it?

Answer (score 26):

You want to achieve the following (cut from `values.yaml` from `prometheus` helm chart):

```
alertmanager:
  ingress:
    ## If true, alertmanager Ingress will be created
    ##
    enabled: true

    ## alertmanager Ingress annotations
    ##
    annotations: {
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing, 
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: 'Environment=dev,Team=test'
    }
```

According to [helm documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/using_helm.md), the structure:

```
alertmanager:
  ingress:
    annotations:
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
```

is

```
--set alertmanager.ingress.annotations."alb\.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/scheme"=internet-facing
```

If you want to add one more annotation, it will be one more `--set` statement:

```
--set alertmanager.ingress.annotations."alb\.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/tags"="Environment=dev\,Team=test"
```

And one more thing, `name: "value1,value2"` is `--set name=value1\,value2`, so `Environment=dev,Team=test` is `"Environment=dev\,Team=test"`.

The final helm command is:

```
helm install stable/prometheus --set alertmanager.ingress.enabled=true --set alertmanager.ingress.annotations."alb\.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/scheme"=internet-facing --set alertmanager.ingress.annotations."alb\.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/tags"="Environment=dev\,Team=test"
```

p.s. Above command fails, because you need to specify domain name for alertmanager as well. 
The correct one is:

```
helm install stable/prometheus --set alertmanager.ingress.enabled=true --set alertmanager.ingress.annotations."alb\.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/scheme"=internet-facing --set alertmanager.ingress.annotations."alb\.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/tags"="Environment=dev\,Team=test" --set alertmanager.ingress.hosts[0]=alertmanager.domain.com
```