# How to add extraScrapeConfigs to Prometheus helm chart from --set argument?

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I want to deploy Prometheus from the official helm chart on the `stable` repo.

Also, I want to add my own scrape config.

I can successfully add extra configs directly from the `values.yml` file of the chart, after downloading and altering it, but when I try to pass it as argument with `--set` nothing happens.

This works [in `values.yml`]:

```
# adds additional scrape configs to prometheus.yml
# must be a string so you have to add a | after extraScrapeConfigs:
# example adds prometheus-blackbox-exporter scrape config
extraScrapeConfigs: |
  - job_name: 'sample-job'
    scrape_interval: 1s
    metrics_path: /
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
```

this does not:

```
sudo helm upgrade --install prometheus \
--set rbac.create=true \
--set server.persistentVolume.enabled=false \
--set alertmanager.persistentVolume.enabled=false \
--set alertmanager.enabled=false \
--set kubeStateMetrics.enabled=false \
--set nodeExporter.enabled=false \
--set pushgateway.enabled=false \
--set extraScrapeConfigs="|
  - job_name: 'sample-pods'
    scrape_interval: 1s
    metrics_path: /
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
" \
stable/prometheus
```

Is it possible someway?

I found this SO question [How to use --set to set values with Prometheus chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523661/how-to-use-set-to-set-values-with-prometheus-chart) , but I cannot find a way to apply it to my case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When we are going to inject a multi-line text into values we need to deal with indentation in YAML.

For your particular case it is:

```
sudo helm upgrade --install prometheus \
--set rbac.create=true \
--set server.persistentVolume.enabled=false \
--set alertmanager.persistentVolume.enabled=false \
--set alertmanager.enabled=false \
--set kubeStateMetrics.enabled=false \
--set nodeExporter.enabled=false \
--set pushgateway.enabled=false \
--set extraScrapeConfigs="- job_name: 'sample-pods'
  scrape_interval: 1s
  metrics_path: /
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: endpoints" \
stable/prometheus
```

The more elegant way is to use `--set-file key=filepath` construction instead of `--set`:

**1.** We create `extraScrapeConfigs.yaml` and put there our value as is:

```
- job_name: 'sample-pods'
  scrape_interval: 1s
  metrics_path: /
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: endpoints
```

**2.** We deploy `stable/prometheus` helm chart:

```
sudo helm upgrade --install prometheus \
--set rbac.create=true \
--set server.persistentVolume.enabled=false \
--set alertmanager.persistentVolume.enabled=false \
--set alertmanager.enabled=false \
--set kubeStateMetrics.enabled=false \
--set nodeExporter.enabled=false \
--set pushgateway.enabled=false \
--set-file extraScrapeConfigs=extraScrapeConfigs.yaml \
stable/prometheus
```

Comment: Thank you Nickolay ! I am still wondering why these things are not well documented though.